# What 1960s era launch pad and vehicle is shown in this still from stock footage?

Tags: history, identify-this-object, launch-site

The interesting question [Identify this 1960's launch site and mission?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/24435/identify-this-1960s-launch-site-and-mission) contains some screenshots of launch pad stock footage.  Most are of LC39, but as @Puffin points out in a comment, one does not appear to be.

What launch pad and vehicle is depicted here? (I do not seek the exact mission vehicle depicted, just the type, e.g. Atlas, Delta, etc.)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tentatively id'd as LC37 (Saturn 1 vehicles) in the foreground and LC34 (also Saturn 1) in the background.

A modern Google Earth image shows the pattern of crossing roads between the pads as visible in the screenshot.

[image]

There also appears to be a [Mobile Support Structure](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/43842/6944) parked at the foreground pad.  Seen here in an image from the [Pad 37 Fact Sheet](https://www.spaceline.org/cape-canaveral-launch-sites/launch-complex-37-saturn-fact-sheet/)

[image]

Pad 34 of course was the site of the Apollo 1 fire. (personal photo)

[image]